Interpreting a matrix equation with "matricised" eigenvalues
I am actually interested in understanding the relationship between eigenvalues of matrix $P \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ and matrix $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{2n \times 2n}$ defined as
$$Q=\begin{pmatrix} \Re[P] & -\Im[P] \\ \Im[P] & \Re[P] \end{pmatrix}$$
So, I started with writing $Pu = \lambda u$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ and $P = L + i M$ and $u=x+iy$ and this lead me to
\begin{equation}
Q \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} L & -M\\
M & L
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} \Re[\lambda] & -\Im[\lambda]\\
\Im[\lambda] & Re[\lambda]
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Now it is clear that if $\lambda$ is real, then it is also an eigenvalue of $Q$. But what if $\lambda$ is not real? What would be the eigenvalues of $Q$ in then?

How are the occurrences of the letter $u$ in (1) "So, I started with writing $Pu = \lambda u$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ and $P = L + i M$"  and (2) "and this lead me to
$
Q \begin{pmatrix} u \ v \end{pmatrix} = \ldots $" related?

My apologies. thanks for pointing out @JohnHughes

If $u$ is a complex eigenvector of $P$, it can be written as
$$
u = s + it
$$
where $s$ and $t$ are real $n$-vectors. You might want to look at
$$
Q \pmatrix{s\\t}
$$
and see whether, perhaps, the real $2n$-vector $\pmatrix{s\\t}$ is in fact an eigenvector of $Q$.
I haven't actually worked it out, but given that you've split $Q$ into real and imaginary parts, it makes sense to do so for the eigenvector, too. And while you're at it, try writing $\lambda = a + ib$, where $a$ and $b$ are real. In other words: convert everything to equations involving the real and imaginary parts of your original equation and its solutions, and see where that gets you.
Post-comment addition
I tried this out in Matlab, picking a couple of 2x2 matrices at random to be $L$ and $M$. (Not truly "at random" -- the first couple that jumped into my head as I typed!).
Here is the program (with annotation) and the highly-suggestive results, which seem to match what I thought would happen, but with a bit of a twist.
L = [1 3; 2 1].  % L is a matrix with 1st row 1 3; 2nd row 2 1
M = [2, 0; 2 5] % similar for M
eig(L) % Print the eigenvalues of L
eig(M) % and of M
eig(L + i*M) % Then print the eigenvalues of P = L + iM

Q = [L -M; M L]; % Construct the 4x4 matrix Q from the problem statement
eig(Q) % and show its eigenvalues as well. 

Results:
L =
 1     3
 2     1

M =
 2     0
 2     5

ans =   % eigenvalues of L
3.4495

-1.4495
ans =   % eigenvalues of M
 5
 2

ans =   % Eigenvalues of P = L + iM

-1.3265 + 2.2105i
3.3265 + 4.7895i
ans =   % Eigenvalues of Q

3.3265 + 4.7895i
3.3265 - 4.7895i
-1.3265 + 2.2105i
-1.3265 - 2.2105i
That's seems mighty suggestive to me. I think you need to go back and try writing out what you know in terms of $s, t, a,$ and $b$ once again.

No luck @John Hughes. Do you have any more suggestions?

See post-comment addition. So I guess my suggestion is "Go back and try that again, because perhaps you made some algebraic error. And write out what you did by editing your answer, so that we can help you see where you might have gone wrong or stalled out."

Say $\lambda = re^{i\theta}$, and let the other notation be as in your question. Then observe that $Q$ acts on your vector $\begin{bmatrix}x\\ 
 y\end{bmatrix}$ as a rotation and scaling:
$$ Q\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix} = r\begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix}. $$
From this we might expect a complex eigenvalue. In fact, you can check that
$$ Q\begin{bmatrix} x - iy \\ y + ix \end{bmatrix} = \lambda \begin{bmatrix} x - iy \\ y + ix \end{bmatrix}. $$
Since we have doubled the dimension, we also expect $Q$ to have twice as many eigenvalues as $P$. This corresponds (roughly) to choosing the phase of the eigenvector $u$ — for any $z \in \mathbb{C}$ we have another eigenvector $zu$. If $\lambda$ is real, then $iu$ gives us the eigenvector $\begin{bmatrix} -y \\ x\end{bmatrix}$, and in general we get the complex conjugate:
$$ Q\begin{bmatrix} x + iy \\ y - ix \end{bmatrix} = \lambda^* \begin{bmatrix} x + iy \\ y - ix \end{bmatrix}. $$
